# How to delete only a line from the canvas, not all the drawings?

Tags: javascript, html, qt, canvas, qml

The solution I found is to [clear the whole canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142535/how-to-clear-the-canvas-for-redrawing), but I only want to delete one line not all drawings on the canvas.

What should I do?

Comment: Does it have anything to do with Qt?

Comment: @Tay2510 yes, qml too has a canvas, and the same answer will apply there too. Qml is a part of qt so it will be easier for others to search.

Comment: Please post the code that demonstrates how you draw and on what canvas. It's not clear at all as to what you're doing. The html5 canvas can be modified, so I don't really understand your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no simple way to do that, as the previous information of the pixels are lost after you draw anything.
Here you've a better answer: [clear line on HTML5 Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6629386/clear-line-on-html5-canvas)

> In computer graphics when drawing something, you draw to a buffer. And
>   when you call lineTo and stroke the buffer is updated and all
>   information that were in the underlying pixels are lost (or partly
>   lost if you use transparency) and there is no way to get it back by
>   undoing (unless there is an implementation containing loads of old
>   drawings, but that would be really heavy for the memory).
>
> So to be able to undo a stroke might save alot of CPU/GPU time BUT
>   whould heavily increase the memory

So the only way seems to use clearRect.

Answer (score 8):

@danielfranca is right that a line drawn onto the canvas becomes *"unremembered pixels in the canvas's sea of pixels."*

He's also right that saving snapshot images of the canvas as each line is drawn and reverting to one of those saved images to "delete" a line is resource intensive. (Don't use that technique!!)

**But, there is an efficient way to delete previously drawn lines on a canvas!**

Yes, it does clear the canvas and redraw the lines, but it's very fast & efficient...I promise!

Here's an outline of how to do it:

- Define a line inside an object like this: `{ x0:10, y0:15, x1:100, y1:75 }`
- Make as many of those lines as desired and push them into an array: `var lines=[];`
- Use the line definitions in the lines[] array to draw your lines onto the canvas.
- Listen for `mousemove` and `mousedown` events.
- On mousemove, iterate throught lines[] and find the line closest to the mouse. Here's a snippet of the algorithm that calculates which line is closest to a given [mx,my]:

  ```
  // Find the index of the line closest to mx,my
  function setClosestLine(mx,my) {
      //
      closestLineIndex=-1;
      var minDistanceSquared=100000000;
      //
      // examine each line & 
      // determine which line is closest to the mouse (mx,my)
      for(var i=0;i<lines.length;i++){
          var line=lines[i];
          var dx=line.x1-line.x0;
          var dy=line.y1-line.y0;
          var t=((mx-line.x0)*line.dx+(my-line.y0)*line.dy)/line.dx2dy2;
          var x=lerp(line.x0, line.x1, t);
          var y=lerp(line.y0, line.y1, t);
          var dx1=mx-x;
          var dy1=my-y;
          var distSquared=dx1*dx1+dy1*dy1;
          if(distSquared<minDistanceSquared){
              minDistanceSquared=distSquared;
              closestLineIndex=i;
              closestX=x;
              closestY=y;
          }
      }
  };
  ```
- On mousedown, use `lines.splice(targetIndex,1)` to remove the definition of the closest line from the lines[] array. Then clear the canvas and redraw the remaining lines.

Here's annotated code and a Demo:

```js
// canvas related variables
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;
function reOffset(){
    var BB=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    offsetX=BB.left;
    offsetY=BB.top;        
}
var offsetX,offsetY;
reOffset();
window.onscroll=function(e){ reOffset(); }


ctx.lineWidth=2;

// linear interpolation -- needed in setClosestLine()
var lerp=function(a,b,x){ return(a+x*(b-a)); };

// vars to track which line is closest to the mouse
var closestLineIndex=-1;
var closestX,closestY;

// make some random lines and save them in lines[]
var n=5;
var lines=[];
var randomX=function(){return(Math.random()*cw*.67);}
var randomY=function(){return(Math.random()*ch*.67);}
var lastX=randomX();
var lastY=randomY();
for(var i=0;i<n;i++){
    var x=Math.random()*cw*.67;
    var y=Math.random()*ch*.67;
    var dx=x-lastX;
    var dy=y-lastY;
    var line={
        x0:lastX,
        y0:lastY,
        x1:x,
        y1:y,
        weight:Math.round(Math.random()*20),
        // precalc often used values
        dx:dx,
        dy:dy,
        dx2dy2:dx*dx+dy*dy,
    };
    lines.push(line);
    lastX=x;
    lastY=y;
}


redraw();

$("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});
$("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});


//////////////////////////////
// functions

// Find the index of the line closest to mx,my
function setClosestLine(mx,my) {
    //
    closestLineIndex=-1;
    var minDistanceSquared=100000000;
    //
    // examine each line & 
    // determine which line is closest to the mouse (mx,my)
    for(var i=0;i<lines.length;i++){
        var line=lines[i];
        var dx=line.x1-line.x0;
        var dy=line.y1-line.y0;
        var t=((mx-line.x0)*line.dx+(my-line.y0)*line.dy)/line.dx2dy2;
        var x=lerp(line.x0, line.x1, t);
        var y=lerp(line.y0, line.y1, t);
        var dx1=mx-x;
        var dy1=my-y;
        var distSquared=dx1*dx1+dy1*dy1;
        if(distSquared<minDistanceSquared){
            minDistanceSquared=distSquared;
            closestLineIndex=i;
            closestX=x;
            closestY=y;
        }
    }
};

// clear & redraw all lines
function redraw(){
    
    // clear the canvas
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
    
    // draw all lines
    ctx.strokeStyle='black';
    for(var i=0;i<lines.length;i++){   
        var line=lines[i];
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(line.x0,line.y0);
        ctx.lineTo(line.x1,line.y1);
        ctx.stroke();
    }

    // draw the line closest to the mouse in red
    if(closestLineIndex<0){return;}
    var line=lines[closestLineIndex];
    ctx.strokeStyle='red';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(line.x0,line.y0);
    ctx.lineTo(line.x1,line.y1);
    ctx.stroke();
}

// On mousemove, find line closest to mouse
function handleMouseMove(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

  setClosestLine(mouseX,mouseY);

  redraw();

}

// On mousedown, remove line that was closest to mouse
function handleMouseDown(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    if(closestLineIndex>=0){
        lines.splice(closestLineIndex,1);
        redraw();
    }
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: ivory;
}
#canvas {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Closest line to mouse is drawn in red<br>Click to remove that line.</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you would give a javascript drawing library a try. There is, for example the [oCanvas](http://ocanvas.org/) library, where you draw more object oriented. There is a [remove](http://ocanvas.org/docs/Display-Objects/Base/remove) function which removes drawn objects from the canvas.